# An error appeared in the console in the priority-menu.js in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Im on WordPress engine latest version. The site [maxg5.ru](http://maxg5.ru) The console appeared errors in the file priority-menu.js. Because of this error in the mobile version, menu items are displayed in the wrong order as specified in the admin panel. I think this happened after I deleted the line 228 in **wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\inc\template-functions.php**:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'twentynineteen_add_ellipses_to_nav', 10, 2 );
```

It was necessary to do this to disable this filter in the mobile version and impose a mobile menu as I need. How do you fix errors in the priority-menu.js file? Or maybe it was necessary to disable the filter somehow?

Comment: it searches "hidden-links" class and cannot find. If you had filter with class "hidden-links" - you need to comment out the line where you try to access it (120 line): var hiddenList   = visibleList.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.hidden-links');

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a provided theme, never ever ever make updates to it's files, as they will be overwritten when the theme is updated, and never ever **ever** make updates to WordPress Core files.

WordPress has a series of [Action Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and [Filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) that allow you to dynamically and programatically add and remove elements, functions, and other code to and from your site.

Your first step is to re-add that function that you deleted. Then you'll need to either:

- [Create a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)
- [Create a Must-Use Plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/)
- [Create a Child-Theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)
- or Use a Plugin the executes PHP such as [My Custom Functions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/).

Any of these methods will allow you to remove and extend functionality *properly*. The proper way to remove that line is to make use of the [`remove_filter()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) function:

```
remove_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'twentynineteen_add_ellipses_to_nav', 10 );
```

Lastly, to address your console error, it's because the theme's JavaScript relies on this code:

```
var visibleList  = container.parentNode.querySelector('.main-menu[id]');
var hiddenList   = visibleList.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.hidden-links');
var toggleButton = visibleList.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.main-menu-more-toggle');
```

You're going to need to make sure that the element `.main-menu` (with an Id), has a sibling element. Right now that JS is checked to see if `<div class="main-menu" id="xxx">` exists, and then it checks it's next sibling for hidden links. Since there's no sibling for the main menu, it's spitting out that error. You'll need to address that in however you're adding in your "custom" mobile menu.

Comment: I returned the code back to line 228 in the file **wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\inc\template-functions.php:**
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'twentynineteen_add_ellipses_to_nav', 10, 2 );

Comment: Where should I add this code?
**remove_filter ('wp_nav_menu', 'twentynineteen_add_ellipses_to_nav', 10);**

Comment: Where should I add this code? 
**var visibleList  = container.parentNode.querySelector('.main-menu[id]');
var hiddenList   = visibleList.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.hidden-links');
var toggleButton = visibleList.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.main-menu-more-toggle');**

Comment: It sounds like you may want to enlist the assistance of a developer, which is beyond the scope of what anyone can provide in an answer on Stack Overflow. 

You'll need to add the `remove_filter` code into one of the 4 options I mentioned, Plugin, Must-Use Plugin, Child Theme, or Custom Functions plugin. The last bit of JavaScript is the code that's in the current theme give you the error and is rooted in the 2019 theme.

Comment: OK thanks. Do everything as you said.
Everything worked out. The console left two errors related to your javascript code.
Look here please.

Comment: Maybe I put your JavaScript code in the wrong place?
I pasted in the priority-menu.js file
Where do I need JavaScript code?

Comment: I figured out remove_filter.

JavaScript code has already been provided in the priority-menu.js file
But why errors in the console remained?
Help me please!

Comment: Again, you may want to enlist the help of a developer. The code I gave you isn't *new* to be placed anywhere, it's just the code from the `priority-menu.js`, and I explained *why* you're getting the errors. You need to make sure your HTML is following a similar structure (a sibling after the `main-menu` at the very least) to the menu you unhooked.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem using the code fix code in the **priority-menu.js** file?
What would not change the structure of HTML